# Unity2D player inconsistant jumps

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, move

Player keeps jumping at different height . I searched for some solutions on the internet but none of them worked of i didn't found a good one. I don't know what exactly i did wrong i would like if someone could explain me what and how to solve it.

````
    {

        //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {
            // Move the character by finding the target velocity
            Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(move * 10f, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            // And then smoothing it out and applying it to the character
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);

            // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
        }
        // If the player should jump...
        if (m_Grounded && jump)
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2 (0f, m_JumpForce),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Try instead of Rigibody2D.AddForce, just use `Rigidbody2D.velocity += new Vector2(0,5);` This could also cause some untended side effects. Here [is](https://forum.unity.com/threads/jumping-with-addforce-is-inconsistent.298813/) a forum post that has some ideas for jumping.

Comment: This kinda works. I mean he stopped getting launched into space ... but still got some micro jumps.

Comment: Can you give debug info about the player's velocity after his first jump? It could be that his velocity is still a negative value once the player reaches the ground.

Comment: Don't use plus in `Rigidbody2D.velocity += new Vector2(0,5);`, set it explicitly `Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0,5);`

Comment: OMG Really apreciate it man ! (*facepalm* I don't know why didn't i think of that )